# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.markers.map') render

Tags: javascript, google-maps, react-native

i got this type of error when i run my react-native component, please help me out

undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.markers.map') render
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.markers.map')
render
    c:\projects\myapp\src\components\home\hub.js:87:28

    c:\projects\myapp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactCompositeComponent.js:1045:14
measureLifeCyclePerf
    c:\projects\myapp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactCompositeComponent.js:85:11
_renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext
    c:\projects\myapp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactCompositeComponent.js:1045:8
_renderValidatedComponent
    c:\projects\myapp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactCompositeComponent.js:1075:10
performInitialMount
    c:\projects\myapp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactCompositeComponent.js:484:24
mountComponent
    c:\projects\myapp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactCompositeComponent.js:346:40
mountComponent
    c:\projects\myapp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactReconciler.js:62:6
performInitialMount
    c:\projects\myapp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactCompositeComponent.js:496:6
mountComponent
    c:\projects\myapp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactCompositeComponent.js:346:40
mountComponent
    c:\projects\myapp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactReconciler.js:62:6
mountChildren
    c:\projects\myapp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactMultiChild.js:264:10
initializeChildren
    c:\projects\myapp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\native\ReactNativeBaseComponent.js:74:41
mountComponent
    c:\projects\myapp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\native\ReactNativeBaseComponent.js:212:6
mountComponent
    c:\projects\myapp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactReconciler.js:62:6
performInitialMount
    c:\projects\myapp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactCompositeComponent.js:496:6
mountComponent
    c:\projects\myapp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactCompositeComponent.js:346:40
mountComponent
    c:\projects\myapp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactReconciler.js:62:6
mountChildren
    c:\projects\myapp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactMultiChild.js:264:10
initializeChildren
    c:\projects\myapp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\native\ReactNativeBaseComponent.js:74:41
mountComponent
    c:\projects\myapp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\native\

### this is my code:

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
AppRegistry,
 StyleSheet,
Text,
View
} from 'react-native';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';

export default class Hub extends Component {
 constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state = {
   region: null,
   markers: null,
  mapStyle:null
 };
}

componentWillMount() {
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
   (position) => {
     console.log(position);
      this.setState({
       region: {
        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
        longitude: position.coords.longitude,
        latitudeDelta: 0.01,
        longitudeDelta: 0.01,
      },
      markers: {
        latlng: {
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
        },
        title: 'marker test',
        description: 'ta ta ra',
      },
    });
  }, (error) => {
    console.log(error);
    this.setState({
      region: {
        latitude: 21.035080,
        longitude: 105.793627,
        latitudeDelta: 0.01,
        longitudeDelta: 0.01,
      },
      markers: {
        latlng: {
          latitude: 21.035080,
          longitude: 105.793627,
        },
        title: 'marker test',
        description: 'ta ta ra',
      },
    });
  },
);
}


onRegionChange = (region) => {
  this.setState({ region });
 }

render() {

const { region } = this.props;
const { markers } = this.props;
console.log(region);
return (
  <View style ={styles.container}>
    <MapView
      style={styles.map}
      region={this.state.region}
      onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange}

    >
    {this.state.markers.map(marker => (
      <MapView.Marker
        coordinate={marker.latlng}
        title={marker.title}
        description={marker.description}
      />
    ))}
    </MapView>
  </View>
);
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? The error states clearly that there is `undefined` along the dereferencing path `this.state.markers.map` you need to identify the place where the `undefined` is located, i.e. `this`, `state`, `markers` or `map` and figure out why did it got there. But consider this. Your question is poorly composed, please invest more time and efforts in your question, as more you do so, the better answers you will get.

Comment: yes, i have tried! thank you for your advice, i will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Initialize state with `markers = [];` not with `null`.
  then
- set them as array (in `componentDidMount` or in `useEffect` if you are using hooks):

  markers:

  ```
  [{
          latlng: {
            latitude: 21.035080,
            longitude: 105.793627,
          },
          title: 'marker test',
          description: 'ta ta ra',
        }],
  ```

  not as a single object, so you can display them using the `map` function.

After modifications/debugging, if your code still doesn't work, take a look at this fully functional example using multiple markers:

https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/example/examples/DefaultMarkers.js

Answer (score 2):

Your marker is an object and changes it into an Array so that in the initial state make it as Array, not null (map is for Array).

If you want to set null in the initial state change the code like this,

```
    {this.state.markers && this.state.markers.map(marker => (
          <MapView.Marker
            coordinate={marker.latlng}
            title={marker.title}
            description={marker.description}
          />
        ))}
```